# Re-execute target when specified as dependency to multiple rules

Tags: build-process, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following GNU makefile:

```
.PHONY a b c d

a: b c
b: d
c: d
d:
    echo HI
```

I would like the target 'd' to be run twice -- since it is specified as a dependency by both b & c.  Unfortunately, the target 'd' will be executed only once.  The output of running make will simply be 'HI', instead of 'HI  HI'.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

To Clarify, the goal is something like this:

```
subdirs =  a b c

build: x y

x: target=build
x: $(subdirs)

y: target=prepare
y: $(subdirs)

$(subdirs):
    $(make) -f $@/makefile $(target)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
build: x y

x: target=build
y: target=prepare

x y: 
    echo hi $(target) $@
    touch $@
```

See also [GNU Makefile rule generating a few targets from a single source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973445/gnu-makefile-rule-generating-a-few-targets-from-a-single-source-file/4642560#4642560) as it is an answer to a problem that is the opposite of this one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this:

```
.PHONY: a b c

define print-hi
@echo HI
endef

a: b c
b:
    $(print-hi)
c:
    $(print-hi)
```

Comment: Not quite.  More something like this:

subdirs =  a b c

build: x y

x: target=build
x: $(subdirs)

y: target=prepare
z: $(subdirs)

$(subdirs):
    $(make) -f $@/makefile $(target)