# Multiple rules specify the same phony dependent, dependent only executes once

Tags: build-process, makefile, gnu-make

I have a question regarding the GNU makefile example below:

```
.PHONY: $(subdirs) build x y

subdirs =  a b c

build: x y

x: target=prepare
x: $(subdirs)

y: target=build
y: $(subdirs)

$(subdirs):
    $(make) -f $@/makefile $(target)
```

When I run make, I expect make to be called for each sub-directory specifying the target 'prepare' then the target 'build'.  Unfortunately, the $(subdirs) target executes once (making the 'prepare' target), but doesn't execute again for the 'build' target.

It appears that for rule x, make determines the $(subdirs) target needs to be run, but for rule y, the $(subdirs) target is up-to-date.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed you've asked this same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218019.  You should ask each question only once.

Comment: You should *always* use $(MAKE) when invoking make recursively.

Answer (score 4):

The makefile you posted seems to assume that the commands for the `$(subdirs)` target would be run two times: once for `x` and a second time for `y`.  Unfortunately, that's not how makefiles and dependencies work.  The commands for a target are run at most once per make invocation (barring unusual circumstances, such as when makefiles are modified during the make run).

The following will work on UNIX -style systems.  It simply runs the subdirectory makes in a loop, one after each other:

```
subdirs = a b c

.PHONY: build
build:
    for dir in $(subdirs); do \
      $(MAKE) -f $$dir/makefile prepare; \
      $(MAKE) -f $$dir/makefile build; \
    done
```

If you need to build the subdirectories in parallel, you can use the following:

```
subdirs = a b c

.PHONY: build
build: $(addprefix build-,$(subdirs))

define submake-rule
  .PHONY: build-$(1)
  build-$(1):
    $(MAKE) -f $(1)/makefile prepare
    $(MAKE) -f $(1)/makefile build
endef

$(foreach dir,$(subdirs),$(eval $(call submake-rule,$(dir))))
```

This defines a rule `build-<dirname>` for each item in `$(subdirs)`, and makes the `build` target depend on all of them.  As an added bonus, this is portable to Windows as well, without requiring using a Cygwin bash shell or similar.  The downside is that it's a bit harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `Ville`'s method over your attempt.
There are generally two ways to get a multiple run with varying arguments.

1. Write an outer script (or, like `Ville`'s idea iterate within the outer Makefile)

   - Write an `all` rule in each sub-Makefile to run `prepare` followed with `build`
   - this will integrate the `prepare+build` combination within the sub-Makefiles and,
     you would be just running an `all` from the outer Makefile -- much more modular.

This is one example where you can easily land up with an unnecessarily complex `Makefile`

Comment: +1, definitely a good idea to make the prepare+build logic local to each subdirectory.