# Generate multiple target using single action/rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How do I write a rule to generate set of files using a single action.

Example:
Files `x`, `y`, `z` are generated as a result of single execution of script `t.sh` which takes file `a` as input.

```
x y z: a
    t.sh $@
```

GNU make tries to execute `t.sh` 3 times.

Comment: Thanks for pointing! :)
It was difficult to search for this question in archives.

Comment: just added an answer that works (well) to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973445/gnu-makefile-rule-generating-a-few-targets-from-a-single-source-file

Comment: @Beta If you still believe this Q is a duplicate, then vote again please. So that this doesn't age away.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor If you still believe this Q is a duplicate, then vote again please. So that this doesn't age away.

Comment: @shoban If you still believe this Q is a duplicate, then vote again please. So that this doesn't age away.

Answer (score 14):

You could implement one of the solutions specified in the [automake manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Multiple-Outputs.html).

Because you've tagged this `gnumake`, I should also point out that using a GNU make pattern rule (the ones with `%`) with multiple targets WILL consider both generated from one execution of the rule: see the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/make/Pattern-Examples.html#Pattern-Examples).