# Why does this makefile only work with a single job?

Tags: multithreading, makefile, download, cross-compiling

I'm trying to write a `Makefile` which compiles a cross compiler.
It downloads `GCC` and `binutils`, extract the archive, run the `configure` script and run make.

This is the `Makefile` I wrote:

```
# Versions
GCC_VERSION := 6.3.0
BINUTILS_VERSION := 2.27

# Build
TARGET ?= i686-elf
PREFIX := $(realpath build)

# Phony tasks
.PHONY: all clean gcc binutils

# Targets
BINUTILS_TARGETS := build/bin/${TARGET}-addr2line build/bin/${TARGET}-ar \
    build/bin/${TARGET}-as build/bin/${TARGET}-c++filt \
    build/bin/${TARGET}-elfedit build/bin/${TARGET}-gprof \
    build/bin/${TARGET}-ld build/bin/${TARGET}-ld.bfd build/bin/${TARGET}-nm \
    build/bin/${TARGET}-objcopy build/bin/${TARGET}-objdump \
    build/bin/${TARGET}-ranlib build/bin/${TARGET}-readelf \
    build/bin/${TARGET}-size build/bin/${TARGET}-strings \
    build/bin/${TARGET}-strip
GCC_TARGETS := build/bin/${TARGET}-cpp build/bin/${TARGET}-gcc \
    build/bin/${TARGET}-gcc-${GCC_VERSION} build/bin/${TARGET}-gcc-ar \
    build/bin/${TARGET}-gcc-nm build/bin/${TARGET}-gcc-ranlib \
    build/bin/${TARGET}-gcov build/bin/${TARGET}-gcov-tool

# Aliases
all: binutils gcc
gcc: ${GCC_TARGETS}
binutils: ${BINUTILS_TARGETS}

# Download the packages
packages/gcc-${GCC_VERSION}.tar.bz2:
    curl ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-${GCC_VERSION}/gcc-${GCC_VERSION}.tar.bz2 \
        -o $@
packages/binutils-${BINUTILS_VERSION}.tar.bz2:
    curl ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-${BINUTILS_VERSION}.tar.bz2 \
        -o $@

# Extract them
packages/gcc-${GCC_VERSION}/configure: packages/gcc-${GCC_VERSION}.tar.bz2
    tar -xmjf $< -C packages
packages/binutils-${BINUTILS_VERSION}/configure: packages/binutils-${BINUTILS_VERSION}.tar.bz2
    tar -xmjf $< -C packages

# Build them
${GCC_TARGETS}: packages/gcc-${GCC_VERSION}/configure
    mkdir -p build/gcc
    cd build/gcc && ../../packages/gcc-${GCC_VERSION}/configure \
        --target=${TARGET} --prefix=${PREFIX} --disable-nls \
        --enable-languages=c --without-headers && make all-gcc && \
        make all-target-libgcc && make install-gcc && make install-target-libgcc
${BINUTILS_TARGETS}: packages/binutils-${BINUTILS_VERSION}/configure
    mkdir -p build/binutils
    cd build/binutils && ../../packages/binutils-${BINUTILS_VERSION}/configure \
        --target=${TARGET} --prefix=${PREFIX} --with-sysroot --disable-nls \
        --disable-werror && make && make install

# Clean everything
clean:
    rm -rf build/*
    rm -rf packages/*
```

It works when running `make` with no options, but when I use the jobs option, it fails (but not everytime): it download `binutils` and `GCC` in parallel.

When binutils is fully downloaded, it extracts it and compiles it, then the `GCC` download ends, but it doesn't do anything and there are no errors.

Also sometimes the compilation of `GCC` or `binutils` fails with strange errors (I will edit this post with some of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the exact source of your specific build failures, but the Makefile is problematic: the 2 build rules have multiple targets.  Make does not support this well, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081284/gnu-make-multiple-targets-in-a-single-rule) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Make with jobs fails because it starts multiple instances of the same recipe but these instances can't run together correctly.

```
${GCC_TARGETS}: packages/gcc-${GCC_VERSION}/configure
    mkdir -p build/gcc
    cd build/gcc && ../../packages/gcc-${GCC_VERSION}/configure ... make ...
```

This is trouble maker, I guess, because Make with jobs initiates multiple configure invocations in the same directory to run asynchronously. So you have multiple configure scripts running and adding bits to the same directory. And then multiple instances of Make are invoked in the same build directory. Perfect mess.

Something like:

```
${GCC_TARGETS}: packages/gcc-${GCC_VERSION}/configure
    mkdir -p build/gcc/$(nodir $@) && cd build/gcc/$(nodir $@) ...
```

Should fix the problem by means of starting configure & make sequences in different directories. You need similar fix for ${BINUTILS_TARGETS} too.