# Clean up unmentioned intermediate files in Make

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile that builds a shapefile as an intermediate steps.

```
.INTERMEDIATE : senate_boundaries.shp
senate_boundaries.shp : Senate\ shape\ files.zip
     unzip -j "$<"
```

A full shapefile comes with more than just a `.shp`, but also a `.prj` file, a `.dbf` file, and a bunch of others. These files are created when "Senate shape files.zip" is unzipped.

These other files are never an explicit target or dependency.

```
.INTERMEDIATE : senate_boundaries.prj senate_boundaries.dbf
```

does not seem to do anything.

How can I tell Make to clean up these other files?

Comment: make doesn't know anything about them (even despite marking them `INTERMEDIATE`) so I'm not sure it should delete them from that. What generates the `.prj` and `.dbf` files?

Comment: They are in the zip file.

Comment: The best I think you could do is use the feature of pattern rules described in the last paragraph [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Examples) and then use something like `senate_boundarie%.shp senate_boundarie%.prj senate_boundarie%.dbf: Senate\ shape\ files.zip` which should have make handle them correctly. (Though you should really consider getting rid of the spaces in the zip file name make *really* doesn't do well with spaces in file names.)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973445/gnu-makefile-rule-generating-a-few-targets-from-a-single-source-file

Answer (score 1):

You can add something like this to your recipe:

```
rm -f $(wildcard Senate\shape\*.prj)
```

But that will only work for that one file and you would have to manually add each extension to get rid of.

so something like this might do the trick:

```
rm -f $(shell ls Senate\shape\ | grep -v .shp&)
```

Another option is to unzip into a temp directory and then copy the file you want out and remove the the temp directory.