# How to prevent Webpack from running several times from Makefile recipes

Tags: makefile, build, webpack, gnu-make

This is, presumably, more a `make` than a `webpack` question.

I'm using good ol' `make` to manage dependencies and builds, and `webpack` for building JS components. Example:

Makefile:

```
foo.js: src/foo.js
    webpack -p

bar.js: src/bar.js
    webpack -p
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
      'foo': './src/foo.js',
      'bar': './src/bar.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: '[name].js',
    }
};
```

Quite obviously, every time when any of `src/{foo,bar}.js` changes, Webpack runs and builds both files. This might not be fixable, as I've read that this is on purpose (to cater for possible interactions between the modules).

However, when *both* change, Webpack will run twice, because the recipes don't know of each other. This is unnecessary and gets out of hand quickly.

Is there any possibility to "collect" the files and make Webpack only run once, independently of how many source files changed?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the entry point from the command line:

```
foo.js: src/foo.js package.json
    webpack -p --entry src/foo.js

bar.js: src/bar.js package.json
    webpack -p --entry src/bar.js
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried that, too, actually, but to no avail. There might be differences between v1 and v2 of Webpack, but my v1 Webpack just adds the module from the command line to the first module listed in `entry`.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3077254/113195) set me on the right track. GNU Make runs recipes of so-called [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro) only once. So changing my Makefile to this does the trick of running Webpack exactly once:

```
foo.j% bar.j%:
    webpack -p

foo.js: src/foo.js
bar.js: src/bar.js
```