# A make recipe that generates two files, independently

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my makefile I have a recipe that produces two files. If *either* of those two files are out of date, the recipe should run, once. So something like this:

```
file1 file2 : deps
    make_files
```

Note that the `make_files` command always produces both files, and its invocation does not depend on the target (i.e., we don't use the target name or any stem in its invocation).

The problem is that make interprets this as two rules, one for `file1` and one for `file2`, causing it to potentially run `make_files` twice if both are missing (e.g., when using `make -j`), which blows up (`make_files` is actually invoking `make` in another subdirectory and this doesn't work if it is invoked twice concurrently).

Any fix, for example to tell `make` to just run `make_files` once?

Right now the hack I'm using is to make `file2` depend on `file1`, even though it doesn't:

```
file2 : file1
```

This causes `make` to serialize the `make_files` invocations. This doesn't always work well, however: in the case that both files are missing, it will run `make_files` once to make them, but then if `file2` has a later timestamp than `file1`, it will make run `make_files` again.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973445/761374 for the definitive S.O. answers to this question.

Comment: Would you be willing to have a dummy file whose only function is to have a timestamp?

Comment: @Beta - yes, I would.

Answer (score 2):

If your two files really do share a common stem as in your example, then you can use:

```
%1 %2: deps
        make_files
```

Pattern rules, unlike explicit rules, assume that a single invocation of the recipe will create all target patterns.

Comment: The files have a common "middle part". The actual names are `libpfc.so` and `pfc.ko`. So I guess that doesn't work?

Comment: @Beta - ok, right, but only if I don't have any other `.so` or `.ko` files being built in this Makefile, right?

Comment: If you use explicit or static pattern rules to build your other `.so` / `.ko` targets then they won't interfere.